# Как убрать точки?

Tags: css, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, вопрос следующий - при наборе кода в visual studio при нажатии на tab появляются эти довольно неприятные точки. Как их убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал убирать галочку с "Поле структуры", но это не помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервис > Параметры > Параметры текстового редактора

Здесь Вы найдете строку "Поля структуры". Отключите ее.

Comment: Не помогло. Как я понял, дело не в структуре, так как когда я их отключил вообще, эти точки всё равно остались

Comment: не могли бы Вы скинуть скриншот меню, в котором убираете галочку?

Comment: Прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: @igor_bal кажется я ошибся с точным переводом на русский, попробуйте отключить последний флажок, т.е. "Показать направляющие структуры"

Comment: Спасибо большое, это помогло!

Answer (score 2):

Вид > Показать/Скрыть символы пробелов

Comment: Облазил там всё, но правила для точек я не нашел

Comment: Ответ более общий. Пожалуйста измените свой ответ, для решения задачи, конкретно указав пункт и настройку.

Comment: Насколько общий вопрос, настолько общий ответ. Но если не хочется думать, то Ctrl + R, Ctrl + W. Полагаю объяснять не надо как работают сочетания клавиш в студии?

Comment: Это также не работает